# one line cmd command to elevate and check if file was copy or no

Tags: batch-file, command-line, cmd, vbscript, scripting

```
Echo Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) > "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"&Echo UAC.ShellExecute "cmd", "/c ""copy %appdata%\test.exe %windir%\syswow64""", "", "runas", 1 >> "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"&start "" cscript %temp%\getadmin.vbs /realtime& ping localhost -n 3>nul & del /Q getadmin.vbs & cls & exit
```

I want to add a verify code to check if **test.exe** was succefully copy in syswow64 and if is not copy then show AGAIN the elevated UAC PROMPT ! - i mean if user press NO button to elevated uac prompt then will appear again the UAC prompt - and if user will press YES then script will see the test.exe in syswow64 then will exit !

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question is much to hard to read as it is, without any formatting or line breaks. Please review [How to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: i need to implenet something like this : 
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If (fso.FileExists(path)) Then
   msg = path & " exists."
Else
  APPER AGAIN THE UACPROMP
End If